# Android material design pre lollipop activity transitions

Tags: android, intellij-idea, material-design, activity-transition

I created an App using android material design support library and it works perfectly fine.I have tried to include Activity transitions using this library
[here](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations) but i don't know where to start since it's built with gradle and I've no idea about it.(I'm using intellij idea for my project).Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this library is very simple and works exactly like all other gradle libraries with public aar distributions. You can find tons of information on the Internet. For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Euo6xzCwY4

And btw, this library works only on Lollipop and Marshmallow. Official activity transitions are only for 5.+. This backport library should work: https://github.com/takahirom/PreLollipopTransition. You can also find few ideas on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3H7nJ4QaD8